# How can I prevent the Rust benchmark library from optimizing away my code?

Tags: optimization, rust, benchmarking

I have a simple idea I'm trying to benchmark in Rust. However, when I go to measure it using `test::Bencher`, the base case that I'm trying to compare against:

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use test::black_box;
    use test::Bencher;

    const ITERATIONS: usize = 100_000;

    struct CompoundValue {
        pub a: u64,
        pub b: u64,
        pub c: u64,
        pub d: u64,
        pub e: u64,
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_in_place(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let mut compound_value = CompoundValue {
            a: 0,
            b: 2,
            c: 0,
            d: 5,
            e: 0,
        };

        let val: &mut CompoundValue = &mut compound_value;

        let result = b.iter(|| {
            let mut f : u64 = black_box(0);
            for _ in 0..ITERATIONS {
                f += val.a + val.b + val.c + val.d + val.e;
            }
            f = black_box(f);
            return f;
        });
        assert_eq!((), result);
    }
}
```

is optimized away entirely by the compiler, resulting in:

```
running 1 test
test tests::bench_in_place ... bench:           0 ns/iter (+/- 1)
```

As you can see in the gist, I have tried to employ the suggestions [set forth in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/benchmark-tests.html#gotcha:-optimizations), namely:

- Making use of the `test::black_box` method to hide implementation details from the compiler.
- Returning the calculated value from the closure passed to the `iter` method.

Are there any other tricks I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the compiler can see that the result of the loop is the same every time `iter` calls the closure (just add some constant to `f`) because `val` never changes.

Looking at the assembly (by passing `--emit asm` to the compiler) demonstrates this:

```
_ZN5tests14bench_in_place20h6a2d53fa00d7c649yaaE:
    ; ...
    movq    %rdi, %r14
    leaq    40(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   _ZN3sys4time5inner10SteadyTime3now20had09d1fa7ded8f25mjwE@PLT
    movq    (%r14), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .LBB0_3
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rcx
    movl    $700000, %edx
.LBB0_2:
    movq    $0, 24(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    movq    24(%rsp), %rsi
    addq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rsi, 24(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    movq    24(%rsp), %rsi
    movq    %rsi, 24(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    decq    %rax
    jne .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rbx
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   _ZN3sys4time5inner10SteadyTime3now20had09d1fa7ded8f25mjwE@PLT
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
    leaq    40(%rsp), %rdx
    movq    %rbx, %rsi
    callq   _ZN3sys4time5inner30_$RF$$u27$a$u20$SteadyTime.Sub3sub20h940fd3596b83a3c25kwE@PLT
    movups  8(%rsp), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, 8(%r14)
    addq    $56, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    retq
```

The section between `.LBB0_2:` and `jne .LBB0_2` is what the call to `iter` compiles down to, it is repeatedly running the code in the closure that you passed to it. The `#APP` `#NO_APP` pairs are the `black_box` calls. You can see that the `iter` loop doesn't do much: `movq` is just moving data from register to/from other registers and the stack, and `addq`/`decq` are just adding and decrementing some integers.

Looking above that loop, there's `movl    $700000, %edx`: This is loading the constant `700_000` into the edx register... and, suspiciously, `700000 = ITEARATIONS * (0 + 2 + 0 + 5 + 0)`. (The other stuff in the code isn't so interesting.)

The way to disguise this is to `black_box` the input, e.g. I might start off with the benchmark written like:

```
#[bench]
fn bench_in_place(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let mut compound_value = CompoundValue {
        a: 0,
        b: 2,
        c: 0,
        d: 5,
        e: 0,
    };

    b.iter(|| {
        let mut f : u64 = 0;
        let val = black_box(&mut compound_value);
        for _ in 0..ITERATIONS {
            f += val.a + val.b + val.c + val.d + val.e;
        }
        f
    });
}
```

In particular, `val` is `black_box`'d inside the closure, so that the compiler can't precompute the addition and reuse it for each call.

However, this is still optimised to be very fast: 1 ns/iter for me. Checking the assembly again reveals the problem (I've trimmed the assembly down to just the loop that contains the `APP`/`NO_APP` pairs, i.e. the calls to `iter`'s closure):

```
.LBB0_2:
    movq    %rcx, 56(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    movq    56(%rsp), %rsi
    movq    8(%rsi), %rdi
    addq    (%rsi), %rdi
    addq    16(%rsi), %rdi
    addq    24(%rsi), %rdi
    addq    32(%rsi), %rdi
    imulq   $100000, %rdi, %rsi
    movq    %rsi, 56(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    decq    %rax
    jne .LBB0_2
```

Now the compiler has seen that `val` doesn't change over the course of the `for` loop, so it has correctly transformed the loop into just summing all the elements of `val` (that's the sequence of 4 `addq`s) and then multiplying that by `ITERATIONS` (the `imulq`).

To fix this, we can do the same thing: move the `black_box` deeper, so that the compiler can't reason about the value between different iterations of the loop:

```
#[bench]
fn bench_in_place(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let mut compound_value = CompoundValue {
        a: 0,
        b: 2,
        c: 0,
        d: 5,
        e: 0,
    };

    b.iter(|| {
        let mut f : u64 = 0;
        for _ in 0..ITERATIONS {
            let val = black_box(&mut compound_value);
            f += val.a + val.b + val.c + val.d + val.e;
        }
        f
    });
}
```

This version now takes 137,142 ns/iter for me, although the repeated calls to `black_box` probably cause non-trivial overhead (having to repeatedly write to the stack, and then read it back).

We can look at the asm, just to be sure:

```
.LBB0_2:
    movl    $100000, %ebx
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_3:
    movq    %rdx, 56(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    movq    56(%rsp), %rax
    addq    (%rax), %rdi
    addq    8(%rax), %rdi
    addq    16(%rax), %rdi
    addq    24(%rax), %rdi
    addq    32(%rax), %rdi
    decq    %rbx
    jne .LBB0_3
    incq    %rcx
    movq    %rdi, 56(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    cmpq    %r8, %rcx
    jne .LBB0_2
```

Now the call to `iter` is two loops: the outer loop that calls the closure many times (`.LBB0_2:` to `jne .LBB0_2`), and the `for` loop inside the closure (`.LBB0_3:` to `jne .LBB0_3`). The inner loop is indeed doing a call to `black_box` (`APP`/`NO_APP`) followed by 5 additions. The outer loop is setting `f` to zero (`xorl %edi, %edi`), running the inner loop, and then `black_box`ing `f` (the second `APP`/`NO_APP`).

(Benchmarking exactly what you want to benchmark can be tricky!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your benchmark is that the optimizer knows that your CompoundValue is going to be immutable during the benchmark, thus it can strengh-reduce the loop and thus compile it down to a constant value.

The solution is to use test::black_box on the parts of your CompoundValue. Or even better, try to get rid of the loop (unless you want to benchmark loop performance), and let Bencher.iter(..) do it's job.