# Odd results when evaluating benchmark example from Rust Book

Tags: assembly, optimization, rust, benchmarking

## Benchmark tests from Rust Book

I am getting odd results from microbenchmarks that can be reproduced with the the example `bench_xor_1000_ints` from the Rust Book chapter on [Benchmark tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/benchmark-tests.html).

The section [*Gotcha: optimizations*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/benchmark-tests.html#gotcha-optimizations) gives general recommendations to return a value from the `Bencher::iter` closure and/or to use the `black_box` function. I ended up with these five variants:

### Benchmark code

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

use test::{Bencher, black_box};

fn xor(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 { x ^ y }

#[bench]
fn xor_closure_a(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        let n = black_box(1000);
        (0..n).fold(0, |a, b| a ^ b)
    });
}

#[bench]
fn xor_closure_b(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        let n = black_box(1000);
        (0..n).fold(0, |a, b| a ^ b);
    });
}

#[bench]
fn xor_pointer_a(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        let n = black_box(1000);
        (0..n).fold(0, xor)
    });
}

#[bench]
fn xor_pointer_b(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        let n = black_box(1000);
        (0..n).fold(0, xor);
    });
}

#[bench] // closure/pointer or semicolon doesn't affect results
fn xor_black_box(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        black_box((0..1000).fold(0, xor));
    });
}
```

### Benchmark naming

- prefix *xor_closure_*: pass closure `|a, b| a ^ b`
- prefix *xor_pointer_*: pass function pointer `xor`
- suffix *_a*: `b.iter` closure returns value (note lack of semicolon)
- suffix *_b*: `b.iter` closure doesn't return value (ends with semicolon)
- *xor_black_box*: throw everything into `black_box` and hope for the best

### Benchmark results

```
test tests::xor_black_box ... bench:          69 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test tests::xor_closure_a ... bench:          70 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test tests::xor_closure_b ... bench:         921 ns/iter (+/- 5)
test tests::xor_pointer_a ... bench:          60 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test tests::xor_pointer_b ... bench:           0 ns/iter (+/- 0)
```

Some observations regarding measurements:

- Removal of the black-boxed iteration counter `let n = black_box(1000)` and inlining it into range `(0..1000).fold ...` doesn't affect any of the results
- Scaling of the iteration counter `n` scales measurements appropriately (except for `xor_pointer_b` optimized to 0)

On the whole, results agree with the general recommendations from Rust Book, except for `xor_closure_b` benchmark.

More specifically, results with the suffix *_a* (that return a value) seem to agree with the black-boxed *xor_black_box* which sounds good to me. And `xor_pointer_b` optimized to 0 seems legit since its closure doesn't return the value. But the result of `xor_closure_b` is odd.

Assembly code may clarify this question. [How can I prevent the Rust benchmark library from optimizing away my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385805/how-can-i-prevent-the-rust-benchmark-library-from-optimizing-away-my-code) gives a good overview on reading assembly from the Rust benchmark tests.

```
cargo rustc --release -- --emit asm
```

produces [this output](https://gist.github.com/4e6/bbb0dcb93dba5658645a9748ee791d44):

```
    .text
    .file   "fpinrust.cgu-0.rs"
    .section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .p2align    4
.LCPI0_0:
    .long   0
    .long   1
    .long   2
    .long   3
.LCPI0_1:
    .long   4
    .long   4
    .long   4
    .long   4
.LCPI0_2:
    .long   8
    .long   8
    .long   8
    .long   8
.LCPI0_3:
    .long   12
    .long   12
    .long   12
    .long   12
.LCPI0_4:
    .long   16
    .long   16
    .long   16
    .long   16
.LCPI0_5:
    .long   20
    .long   20
    .long   20
    .long   20
.LCPI0_6:
    .long   24
    .long   24
    .long   24
    .long   24
.LCPI0_7:
    .long   28
    .long   28
    .long   28
    .long   28
.LCPI0_8:
    .long   32
    .long   32
    .long   32
    .long   32
    .section    .text._ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_a17h4df097d1e565a700E,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_a17h4df097d1e565a700E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_a17h4df097d1e565a700E,@function
_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_a17h4df097d1e565a700E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r14
.Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    pushq   %rbx
.Ltmp1:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    subq    $40, %rsp
.Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 64
.Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -24
.Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset %r14, -16
    movq    %rdi, %r14
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant3now17h37bccd496c61083dE@PLT
    movq    (%r14), %r9
    testq   %r9, %r9
    je  .LBB0_15
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    leaq    8(%rsp), %r8
    movdqa  .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm8
    movdqa  .LCPI0_1(%rip), %xmm15
    movdqa  .LCPI0_2(%rip), %xmm2
    movdqa  .LCPI0_3(%rip), %xmm9
    movdqa  .LCPI0_4(%rip), %xmm10
    movdqa  .LCPI0_5(%rip), %xmm11
    movdqa  .LCPI0_6(%rip), %xmm12
    movdqa  .LCPI0_7(%rip), %xmm13
    movdqa  .LCPI0_8(%rip), %xmm14
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB0_2:
    incq    %rcx
    movl    $1000, 8(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    movl    8(%rsp), %esi
    testl   %esi, %esi
    movl    $0, %edx
    jle .LBB0_14
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    cmpl    $8, %esi
    jae .LBB0_5
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    jmp .LBB0_13
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB0_5:
    movl    %esi, %eax
    andl    $-8, %eax
    movl    $0, %edi
    je  .LBB0_13
    leal    -8(%rax), %edx
    movl    %edx, %edi
    shrl    $3, %edi
    leal    1(%rdi), %ebx
    andl    $3, %ebx
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm3
    cmpl    $24, %edx
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm4
    movdqa  %xmm8, %xmm5
    jb  .LBB0_9
    leal    -1(%rbx), %edx
    subl    %edi, %edx
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm3
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm4
    movdqa  %xmm8, %xmm5
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB0_8:
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm6
    paddd   %xmm15, %xmm6
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm7
    paddd   %xmm2, %xmm7
    pxor    %xmm5, %xmm3
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm6
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm9, %xmm4
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm0
    paddd   %xmm10, %xmm0
    pxor    %xmm7, %xmm3
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm7
    paddd   %xmm11, %xmm7
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm1
    paddd   %xmm12, %xmm1
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm7
    pxor    %xmm6, %xmm7
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm13, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm14, %xmm5
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm1
    pxor    %xmm1, %xmm3
    pxor    %xmm7, %xmm4
    addl    $4, %edx
    jne .LBB0_8
.LBB0_9:
    testl   %ebx, %ebx
    je  .LBB0_12
    negl    %ebx
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB0_11:
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm0
    pxor    %xmm5, %xmm3
    paddd   %xmm15, %xmm5
    paddd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    pxor    %xmm5, %xmm4
    incl    %ebx
    movdqa  %xmm0, %xmm5
    jne .LBB0_11
.LBB0_12:
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm3
    pshufd  $78, %xmm3, %xmm0
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm0
    pshufd  $229, %xmm0, %xmm1
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm1
    movd    %xmm1, %edx
    cmpl    %eax, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    je  .LBB0_14
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB0_13:
    xorl    %edi, %edx
    leal    1(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    jne .LBB0_13
.LBB0_14:
    movl    %edx, 8(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    cmpq    %r9, %rcx
    jne .LBB0_2
.LBB0_15:
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rsi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant7elapsed17h0b6076720ddfcc2bE@PLT
    movq    8(%rsp), %rax
    movl    16(%rsp), %ecx
    movq    %rax, 8(%r14)
    movl    %ecx, 16(%r14)
    addq    $40, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_a17h4df097d1e565a700E, .Lfunc_end0-_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_a17h4df097d1e565a700E
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    .text._ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_b17h4bdd5e59e5c19a55E,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_b17h4bdd5e59e5c19a55E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_b17h4bdd5e59e5c19a55E,@function
_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_b17h4bdd5e59e5c19a55E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r14
.Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    pushq   %rbx
.Ltmp6:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    subq    $40, %rsp
.Ltmp7:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 64
.Ltmp8:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -24
.Ltmp9:
    .cfi_offset %r14, -16
    movq    %rdi, %r14
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant3now17h37bccd496c61083dE@PLT
    movq    (%r14), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .LBB1_5
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdx
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB1_2:
    movl    $1000, 8(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    movl    8(%rsp), %esi
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB1_3:
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    cmpl    %esi, %ebx
    setl    %dil
    addl    %ebx, %edi
    cmpl    %esi, %ebx
    movl    %edi, %ebx
    jl  .LBB1_3
    incq    %rcx
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    cmpq    %rax, %rcx
    jne .LBB1_2
.LBB1_5:
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rsi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant7elapsed17h0b6076720ddfcc2bE@PLT
    movq    8(%rsp), %rax
    movl    16(%rsp), %ecx
    movq    %rax, 8(%r14)
    movl    %ecx, 16(%r14)
    addq    $40, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    retq
.Lfunc_end1:
    .size   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_b17h4bdd5e59e5c19a55E, .Lfunc_end1-_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_closure_b17h4bdd5e59e5c19a55E
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .p2align    4
.LCPI2_0:
    .long   0
    .long   1
    .long   2
    .long   3
.LCPI2_1:
    .long   4
    .long   4
    .long   4
    .long   4
.LCPI2_2:
    .long   8
    .long   8
    .long   8
    .long   8
.LCPI2_3:
    .long   12
    .long   12
    .long   12
    .long   12
.LCPI2_4:
    .long   16
    .long   16
    .long   16
    .long   16
.LCPI2_5:
    .long   20
    .long   20
    .long   20
    .long   20
.LCPI2_6:
    .long   24
    .long   24
    .long   24
    .long   24
.LCPI2_7:
    .long   28
    .long   28
    .long   28
    .long   28
.LCPI2_8:
    .long   32
    .long   32
    .long   32
    .long   32
    .section    .text._ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_a17hca6c00df2b597ce7E,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_a17hca6c00df2b597ce7E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_a17hca6c00df2b597ce7E,@function
_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_a17hca6c00df2b597ce7E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r14
.Ltmp10:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    pushq   %rbx
.Ltmp11:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    subq    $40, %rsp
.Ltmp12:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 64
.Ltmp13:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -24
.Ltmp14:
    .cfi_offset %r14, -16
    movq    %rdi, %r14
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant3now17h37bccd496c61083dE@PLT
    movq    (%r14), %r9
    testq   %r9, %r9
    je  .LBB2_15
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    leaq    8(%rsp), %r8
    movdqa  .LCPI2_0(%rip), %xmm8
    movdqa  .LCPI2_1(%rip), %xmm15
    movdqa  .LCPI2_2(%rip), %xmm2
    movdqa  .LCPI2_3(%rip), %xmm9
    movdqa  .LCPI2_4(%rip), %xmm10
    movdqa  .LCPI2_5(%rip), %xmm11
    movdqa  .LCPI2_6(%rip), %xmm12
    movdqa  .LCPI2_7(%rip), %xmm13
    movdqa  .LCPI2_8(%rip), %xmm14
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB2_2:
    incq    %rcx
    movl    $1000, 8(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    movl    8(%rsp), %esi
    testl   %esi, %esi
    movl    $0, %edx
    jle .LBB2_14
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    cmpl    $8, %esi
    jae .LBB2_5
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    jmp .LBB2_13
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB2_5:
    movl    %esi, %eax
    andl    $-8, %eax
    movl    $0, %edi
    je  .LBB2_13
    leal    -8(%rax), %edx
    movl    %edx, %edi
    shrl    $3, %edi
    leal    1(%rdi), %ebx
    andl    $3, %ebx
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm3
    cmpl    $24, %edx
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm4
    movdqa  %xmm8, %xmm5
    jb  .LBB2_9
    leal    -1(%rbx), %edx
    subl    %edi, %edx
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm3
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm4
    movdqa  %xmm8, %xmm5
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB2_8:
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm6
    paddd   %xmm15, %xmm6
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm7
    paddd   %xmm2, %xmm7
    pxor    %xmm5, %xmm3
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm6
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm9, %xmm4
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm0
    paddd   %xmm10, %xmm0
    pxor    %xmm7, %xmm3
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm7
    paddd   %xmm11, %xmm7
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm1
    paddd   %xmm12, %xmm1
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm7
    pxor    %xmm6, %xmm7
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm13, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm14, %xmm5
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm1
    pxor    %xmm1, %xmm3
    pxor    %xmm7, %xmm4
    addl    $4, %edx
    jne .LBB2_8
.LBB2_9:
    testl   %ebx, %ebx
    je  .LBB2_12
    negl    %ebx
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB2_11:
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm0
    pxor    %xmm5, %xmm3
    paddd   %xmm15, %xmm5
    paddd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    pxor    %xmm5, %xmm4
    incl    %ebx
    movdqa  %xmm0, %xmm5
    jne .LBB2_11
.LBB2_12:
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm3
    pshufd  $78, %xmm3, %xmm0
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm0
    pshufd  $229, %xmm0, %xmm1
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm1
    movd    %xmm1, %edx
    cmpl    %eax, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    je  .LBB2_14
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB2_13:
    xorl    %edi, %edx
    leal    1(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    jne .LBB2_13
.LBB2_14:
    movl    %edx, 8(%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    cmpq    %r9, %rcx
    jne .LBB2_2
.LBB2_15:
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rsi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant7elapsed17h0b6076720ddfcc2bE@PLT
    movq    8(%rsp), %rax
    movl    16(%rsp), %ecx
    movq    %rax, 8(%r14)
    movl    %ecx, 16(%r14)
    addq    $40, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    retq
.Lfunc_end2:
    .size   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_a17hca6c00df2b597ce7E, .Lfunc_end2-_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_a17hca6c00df2b597ce7E
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    .text._ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_b17h4ef66678d6655ef4E,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_b17h4ef66678d6655ef4E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_b17h4ef66678d6655ef4E,@function
_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_b17h4ef66678d6655ef4E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbx
.Ltmp15:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    subq    $32, %rsp
.Ltmp16:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
.Ltmp17:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -16
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    leaq    16(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant3now17h37bccd496c61083dE@PLT
    movq    (%rbx), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .LBB3_3
    leaq    (%rsp), %rcx
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB3_2:
    movl    $1000, (%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    decq    %rax
    jne .LBB3_2
.LBB3_3:
    leaq    (%rsp), %rdi
    leaq    16(%rsp), %rsi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant7elapsed17h0b6076720ddfcc2bE@PLT
    movq    (%rsp), %rax
    movl    8(%rsp), %ecx
    movq    %rax, 8(%rbx)
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbx)
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    retq
.Lfunc_end3:
    .size   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_b17h4ef66678d6655ef4E, .Lfunc_end3-_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_pointer_b17h4ef66678d6655ef4E
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .p2align    4
.LCPI4_0:
    .long   0
    .long   1
    .long   2
    .long   3
.LCPI4_1:
    .long   4
    .long   4
    .long   4
    .long   4
.LCPI4_2:
    .long   8
    .long   8
    .long   8
    .long   8
.LCPI4_3:
    .long   12
    .long   12
    .long   12
    .long   12
.LCPI4_4:
    .long   16
    .long   16
    .long   16
    .long   16
.LCPI4_5:
    .long   20
    .long   20
    .long   20
    .long   20
.LCPI4_6:
    .long   24
    .long   24
    .long   24
    .long   24
.LCPI4_7:
    .long   28
    .long   28
    .long   28
    .long   28
.LCPI4_8:
    .long   32
    .long   32
    .long   32
    .long   32
.LCPI4_9:
    .long   36
    .long   36
    .long   36
    .long   36
.LCPI4_10:
    .long   40
    .long   40
    .long   40
    .long   40
    .section    .text._ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_black_box17h8af7e6f80fe83dc8E,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_black_box17h8af7e6f80fe83dc8E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_black_box17h8af7e6f80fe83dc8E,@function
_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_black_box17h8af7e6f80fe83dc8E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbx
.Ltmp18:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    subq    $32, %rsp
.Ltmp19:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
.Ltmp20:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -16
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    leaq    16(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant3now17h37bccd496c61083dE@PLT
    movq    (%rbx), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .LBB4_5
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movdqa  .LCPI4_1(%rip), %xmm9
    movdqa  .LCPI4_2(%rip), %xmm10
    movdqa  .LCPI4_3(%rip), %xmm11
    movdqa  .LCPI4_4(%rip), %xmm12
    movdqa  .LCPI4_5(%rip), %xmm13
    movdqa  .LCPI4_6(%rip), %xmm14
    movdqa  .LCPI4_7(%rip), %xmm15
    movdqa  .LCPI4_8(%rip), %xmm0
    movdqa  .LCPI4_9(%rip), %xmm1
    movdqa  .LCPI4_10(%rip), %xmm2
    leaq    (%rsp), %rdx
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB4_2:
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm3
    movl    $1000, %esi
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm4
    movdqa  .LCPI4_0(%rip), %xmm5
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB4_3:
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm6
    paddd   %xmm9, %xmm6
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm7
    paddd   %xmm10, %xmm7
    pxor    %xmm5, %xmm3
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm6
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm11, %xmm4
    pxor    %xmm7, %xmm3
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm7
    paddd   %xmm13, %xmm7
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm7
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm12, %xmm4
    pxor    %xmm6, %xmm7
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm6
    paddd   %xmm14, %xmm6
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm6
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm8
    paddd   %xmm15, %xmm8
    pxor    %xmm6, %xmm3
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm0, %xmm4
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm3
    movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm1, %xmm4
    pxor    %xmm8, %xmm4
    pxor    %xmm7, %xmm4
    paddd   %xmm2, %xmm5
    addl    $-40, %esi
    jne .LBB4_3
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm4
    pshufd  $78, %xmm4, %xmm3
    pxor    %xmm4, %xmm3
    pshufd  $229, %xmm3, %xmm4
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm4
    incq    %rcx
    movd    %xmm4, (%rsp)
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    cmpq    %rax, %rcx
    jne .LBB4_2
.LBB4_5:
    leaq    (%rsp), %rdi
    leaq    16(%rsp), %rsi
    callq   _ZN3std4time7Instant7elapsed17h0b6076720ddfcc2bE@PLT
    movq    (%rsp), %rax
    movl    8(%rsp), %ecx
    movq    %rax, 8(%rbx)
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbx)
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    retq
.Lfunc_end4:
    .size   _ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_black_box17h8af7e6f80fe83dc8E, .Lfunc_end4-_ZN8fpinrust5tests13xor_black_box17h8af7e6f80fe83dc8E
    .cfi_endproc


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Looking at the assembly, `xor_closure_a`, `xor_pointer_a` and `xor_black_box` which all have relatively the same performance, evaluate to similar assembly code. Which is, by the way, a lot more instructions than the amount of ASM for poor `xor_closure_b`.

This is where my research ends. I would be glad if someone explains, why this blanket of assembly produced by `xor_black_box` evaluates faster than `xor_closure_b`. Or put it differently, why the version that should be optimized away by the compiler runs notably slower, and which benchmark variant I should trust?

### Versions

```
rustc --version
rustc 1.13.0-nightly (378195665 2016-09-08)

cargo --version
cargo 0.13.0-nightly (afaffa1 2016-09-06)
```

### Update

@Francis Gagné did a fantastic job to investigate the issue in his answer. The steps that took me to reproduce his results are listed below.

Compile benchmarks and emit assembly:

```
cargo rustc --release -- --test --emit asm
```

Run produced executable to verify previous behavior:

```
./target/release/deps/xor --bench

running 2 tests
test tests::xor_closure_b ... bench:         925 ns/iter (+/- 9)
test tests::xor_pointer_b ... bench:           0 ns/iter (+/- 0)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured
```

Compile patched assembly output `./target/release/deps/xor.s`

```
export RUSTLIB=/path/to/lib/rustlib
gcc target/release/deps/xor.s $RUSTLIB/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/*.rlib $RUSTLIB/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/*.so -pthread -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Run updated benchmarks:

```
./a.out --bench

running 2 tests
test tests::xor_closure_b ... bench:           1 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test tests::xor_pointer_b ... bench:           0 ns/iter (+/- 0)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured
```

Comment: If you have 5 things, and you only care about the difference between two of them, it would be considerate to remove all the extra distractions and produce a focused question.

Comment: @Shepmaster: The fact that only *one* of the 5 functions exhibits poor performance is what makes the question interesting to me. And it shows "what he's tried". :)

Comment: For whatever reason, LLVM is autovectorizing and applying SIMD to all the "fast" ones, but not the `closure_b` variant. The `xmm0` registers and the `vector.body` in the LLVM IR are major hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll focus on comparing `xor_closure_b` and `xor_pointer_b`, since they should have similar performance (i.e. they should both do nothing).

**Update:** I made a mistake in my initial analysis, as pointed out by [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185968/eof), so I revised the text below.

First, let's look at the LLVM IR generated for those two functions. (I find LLVM IR easier to read than ASM because it's more structured.)

```llvm
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define internal void @_ZN3xor13xor_closure_b17hb13913a8d2a27b06E(%"11.test::Bencher"* nocapture dereferenceable(32)) unnamed_addr #0 personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, %"8.unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Exception"*, %"8.unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Context"*)* @rust_eh_personality {
entry-block:
  %dummy.i.i = alloca {}, align 8
  %dummy.i.i.i = alloca i32, align 4
  %start1.i = alloca %"1.std::time::Instant", align 8
  %tmp_ret2.i = alloca %"1.std::time::Duration", align 8
  %1 = bitcast %"1.std::time::Duration"* %tmp_ret2.i to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 16, i8* %1)
  %2 = bitcast %"1.std::time::Instant"* %start1.i to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 16, i8* %2)
  call void @_ZN3std4time7Instant3now17h37bccd496c61083dE(%"1.std::time::Instant"* noalias nocapture nonnull sret dereferenceable(16) %start1.i)
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds %"11.test::Bencher", %"11.test::Bencher"* %0, i64 0, i32 0
  %4 = load i64, i64* %3, align 8
  %5 = icmp eq i64 %4, 0
  br i1 %5, label %_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17h0cab611e22e5c5faE.exit, label %bb7.lr.ph.i

bb7.lr.ph.i:                                      ; preds = %entry-block
  %6 = bitcast i32* %dummy.i.i.i to i8*
  %7 = bitcast {}* %dummy.i.i to i8*
  br label %bb7.i

bb7.i:                                            ; preds = %"_ZN3xor13xor_closure_b28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hbaf8d82981c57ba0E.exit.i", %bb7.lr.ph.i
  %iter.sroa.0.019.i = phi i64 [ 0, %bb7.lr.ph.i ], [ %11, %"_ZN3xor13xor_closure_b28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hbaf8d82981c57ba0E.exit.i" ]
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 4, i8* %6) #2
  store i32 1000, i32* %dummy.i.i.i, align 4
  call void asm "", "r,~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"(i32* nonnull %dummy.i.i.i) #2, !srcloc !1
  %8 = load i32, i32* %dummy.i.i.i, align 4
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 4, i8* %6) #2
  br label %bb7.i.i.i

bb7.i.i.i:                                        ; preds = %bb7.i.i.i, %bb7.i
  %iter.sroa.0.0.i.i.i = phi i32 [ 0, %bb7.i ], [ %iter.sroa.0.1.i.i.i, %bb7.i.i.i ]
  %9 = icmp slt i32 %iter.sroa.0.0.i.i.i, %8
  %10 = zext i1 %9 to i32
  %iter.sroa.0.1.i.i.i = add i32 %10, %iter.sroa.0.0.i.i.i
  br i1 %9, label %bb7.i.i.i, label %"_ZN3xor13xor_closure_b28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hbaf8d82981c57ba0E.exit.i"

"_ZN3xor13xor_closure_b28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hbaf8d82981c57ba0E.exit.i": ; preds = %bb7.i.i.i
  %11 = add nuw i64 %iter.sroa.0.019.i, 1
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 0, i8* %7)
  call void asm "", "r,~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"({}* nonnull %dummy.i.i) #2, !srcloc !1
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 0, i8* %7)
  %exitcond.i = icmp eq i64 %11, %4
  br i1 %exitcond.i, label %_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17h0cab611e22e5c5faE.exit.loopexit, label %bb7.i

_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17h0cab611e22e5c5faE.exit.loopexit: ; preds = %"_ZN3xor13xor_closure_b28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hbaf8d82981c57ba0E.exit.i"
  br label %_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17h0cab611e22e5c5faE.exit

_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17h0cab611e22e5c5faE.exit:   ; preds = %_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17h0cab611e22e5c5faE.exit.loopexit, %entry-block
  call void @_ZN3std4time7Instant7elapsed17h0b6076720ddfcc2bE(%"1.std::time::Duration"* noalias nocapture nonnull sret dereferenceable(16) %tmp_ret2.i, %"1.std::time::Instant"* noalias nonnull readonly dereferenceable(16) %start1.i)
  %12 = getelementptr inbounds %"1.std::time::Duration", %"1.std::time::Duration"* %tmp_ret2.i, i64 0, i32 0
  %13 = getelementptr inbounds %"1.std::time::Duration", %"1.std::time::Duration"* %tmp_ret2.i, i64 0, i32 1
  %14 = load i64, i64* %12, align 8
  %15 = load i32, i32* %13, align 8
  %16 = getelementptr inbounds %"11.test::Bencher", %"11.test::Bencher"* %0, i64 0, i32 1, i32 0
  store i64 %14, i64* %16, align 8
  %17 = getelementptr inbounds %"11.test::Bencher", %"11.test::Bencher"* %0, i64 0, i32 1, i32 1
  store i32 %15, i32* %17, align 4
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 16, i8* %2)
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 16, i8* %1)
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: uwtable
define internal void @_ZN3xor13xor_pointer_b17h7ba0f9760d9fd9f8E(%"11.test::Bencher"* nocapture dereferenceable(32)) unnamed_addr #0 personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, %"8.unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Exception"*, %"8.unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Context"*)* @rust_eh_personality {
entry-block:
  %dummy.i.i = alloca {}, align 8
  %dummy.i.i.i = alloca i32, align 4
  %start1.i = alloca %"1.std::time::Instant", align 8
  %tmp_ret2.i = alloca %"1.std::time::Duration", align 8
  %1 = bitcast %"1.std::time::Duration"* %tmp_ret2.i to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 16, i8* %1)
  %2 = bitcast %"1.std::time::Instant"* %start1.i to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 16, i8* %2)
  call void @_ZN3std4time7Instant3now17h37bccd496c61083dE(%"1.std::time::Instant"* noalias nocapture nonnull sret dereferenceable(16) %start1.i)
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds %"11.test::Bencher", %"11.test::Bencher"* %0, i64 0, i32 0
  %4 = load i64, i64* %3, align 8
  %5 = icmp eq i64 %4, 0
  br i1 %5, label %_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17hae343b1316e5897bE.exit, label %bb7.lr.ph.i

bb7.lr.ph.i:                                      ; preds = %entry-block
  %6 = bitcast i32* %dummy.i.i.i to i8*
  %7 = bitcast {}* %dummy.i.i to i8*
  br label %bb7.i

bb7.i:                                            ; preds = %bb7.i, %bb7.lr.ph.i
  %iter.sroa.0.019.i = phi i64 [ 0, %bb7.lr.ph.i ], [ %8, %bb7.i ]
  %8 = add nuw i64 %iter.sroa.0.019.i, 1
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 4, i8* %6) #2
  store i32 1000, i32* %dummy.i.i.i, align 4
  call void asm "", "r,~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"(i32* nonnull %dummy.i.i.i) #2, !srcloc !1
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 4, i8* %6) #2
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 0, i8* %7)
  call void asm "", "r,~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"({}* nonnull %dummy.i.i) #2, !srcloc !1
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 0, i8* %7)
  %exitcond.i = icmp eq i64 %8, %4
  br i1 %exitcond.i, label %_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17hae343b1316e5897bE.exit.loopexit, label %bb7.i

_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17hae343b1316e5897bE.exit.loopexit: ; preds = %bb7.i
  br label %_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17hae343b1316e5897bE.exit

_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17hae343b1316e5897bE.exit:   ; preds = %_ZN4test7Bencher4iter17hae343b1316e5897bE.exit.loopexit, %entry-block
  call void @_ZN3std4time7Instant7elapsed17h0b6076720ddfcc2bE(%"1.std::time::Duration"* noalias nocapture nonnull sret dereferenceable(16) %tmp_ret2.i, %"1.std::time::Instant"* noalias nonnull readonly dereferenceable(16) %start1.i)
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %"1.std::time::Duration", %"1.std::time::Duration"* %tmp_ret2.i, i64 0, i32 0
  %10 = getelementptr inbounds %"1.std::time::Duration", %"1.std::time::Duration"* %tmp_ret2.i, i64 0, i32 1
  %11 = load i64, i64* %9, align 8
  %12 = load i32, i32* %10, align 8
  %13 = getelementptr inbounds %"11.test::Bencher", %"11.test::Bencher"* %0, i64 0, i32 1, i32 0
  store i64 %11, i64* %13, align 8
  %14 = getelementptr inbounds %"11.test::Bencher", %"11.test::Bencher"* %0, i64 0, i32 1, i32 1
  store i32 %12, i32* %14, align 4
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 16, i8* %2)
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 16, i8* %1)
  ret void
}
```

If we compare the LLVM IR for `xor_closure_b` and `xor_pointer_b`, they look pretty similar. However, one difference stands out: the `bb7.i.i.i` block has been optimized out in `xor_pointer_b`, but not in `xor_closure_b`, for some reason. Here's the block:

```llvm
bb7.i.i.i:                                        ; preds = %bb7.i.i.i, %bb7.i
  %iter.sroa.0.0.i.i.i = phi i32 [ 0, %bb7.i ], [ %iter.sroa.0.1.i.i.i, %bb7.i.i.i ]
  %9 = icmp slt i32 %iter.sroa.0.0.i.i.i, %8
  %10 = zext i1 %9 to i32
  %iter.sroa.0.1.i.i.i = add i32 %10, %iter.sroa.0.0.i.i.i
  br i1 %9, label %bb7.i.i.i, label %"_ZN3xor13xor_closure_b28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hbaf8d82981c57ba0E.exit.i"
```

And here it is translated to ASM:

```
.LBB1_3:
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    cmpl    %esi, %ebx
    setl    %dil
    addl    %ebx, %edi
    cmpl    %esi, %ebx
    movl    %edi, %ebx
    jl  .LBB1_3
```

This is a pretty dumb way to loop from 0 to 1000. Changing the code above to this:

```
.LBB1_3:
    cmpl    %esi, %ebx
    jge .LBB1_3a
    incl    %ebx
    cmpl    %esi, %ebx
    jl  .LBB1_3
.LBB1_3a:
```

makes the benchmark for `xor_closure_b` drop from `781 ns/iter (+/- 19)` to `270 ns/iter (+/- 7)` on my machine.

I cannot say for sure why the code generated by the compiler is so slow, or why it wasn't optimized away in the first place (as it was in `xor_pointer_b`)... However, it seems that `xor_pointer_a` and `xor_closure_a` and faster still because the generated code is vectorized, which has the effect that the loop performs fewer iterations (i.e. the loop is unrolled), by a factor of 32 (e.g. `.LBB0_8`, the main loop in `xor_closure_a`, performs 31 iterations, then the rest is handled after the loop).

For reference, I compiled the edited ASM with this command line:

> `$ gcc target/release/xor-71758a2519026d86.s ~/.multirust/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/lib{test,term,getopts,rustc_unicode,std,libc,rand,collections,alloc_system,alloc,core,panic_unwind}-411f48d3.rlib -pthread -lpthread -lm -ldl`

and I ran it with `./a.out --bench`. Also, my CPU is an Intel Core i7-4770K.

Comment: The `xorl %edi, %edi` is a dependency breaking idiom on modern x86 micro architectures. There will be no partial register stall after subsequent a`setl %dil`, AFAIK.

Comment: Awesome answer. Now, after it settled down in my head, it looks like a regression to me. I mean, `xor_closure_b` should be at least as fast as `xor_black_box`. I am new to Rust ecosystem, do you think it is worth creating an issue regarding this case?

Comment: @EOF: Thanks for the info, I did not know that. But that's not the issue I had identified: I hypothesized that a partial register stall would happen on the `addl %ebx, %edi` following `setl %dil`. I commented out `xorl %edi, %edi` only because it was now redundant, but leaving it in doesn't affect the benchmark.

Comment: @4e6: You might want to file an issue again Rust, but if I'm not mistaken, at the moment, Rust doesn't try very hard to generate optimal LLVM IR, so it might be low priority at the moment.

Comment: You don't think the autovectorization and SIMD operations are involved?

Comment: @Shepmaster: The xor operation has been completely optimized away in both `xor_closure_b` and `xor_pointer_b`. The `xorl` instructions in the assembly only set registers to 0. What is there left to vectorize?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I thought it was "why is this one so much slower than the fast ones (the ones were not optimized away)". The answer to that would have involved the optimizations.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Your conclusion is ludicrous. First of, removing a full register read after a partial register write (after a dependency breaking idiom no less) is not going to improve performance 900-fold. On the other hand, removing an inner loop by commenting out a `cmp` instruction that sets the flags for the loop-condition *will* improve performance arbitrarily. It will also make the program meaningless.

Comment: @EOF: Doh! I completely missed the `jl` instruction. Does this edit make more sense?

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Well, a reduction in runtime to 0.35 is *a lot* more reasonable than one to 0.

Comment: Your updated version is still a pretty dumb way to loop from 0 to 1000.  The cmp/jge don't need to be inside the loop.  The JL target should be just before the INC, or (worse) the CMP/JL should be a JMP (like a C while(){} loop instead of a do{}while() loop after a prologue to test that the loop should run at least once.)